# ¿La palabra "también" puede ir después de una coma?

Tags: gramática, redacción

Consideremos la siguiente oración:

> Pedro dijo: «Juan deberá comprar papa, carne, frutas y verduras, también deberá preguntar el precio de las zapatillas que tanto le gusta.»

Mi duda es: ¿estará bien? ¿En qué casos se puede usar la coma antes de la palabra "también"?

Comment: Creo que la frase es demasiado larga, yo la acortaría, lo haría en varias frases

Comment: Interesante la pregunta, James, y ¡bienvenido al sitio!  // En general he visto que la tolerancia por las *run-on sentences* y *comma splices* es much mayor en español que en inglés.  Este tipo de frase es muy común, por lo menos en México.  Lo que sí se puede decir es que sin esta coma, la oración sería peor.

Answer (score 7):

La palabra "también" puede ir después de una coma, pero no en el caso propuesto, donde estamos en presencia de dos oraciones yuxtapuestas o asindéticas (lo que sería en inglés una *run-on sentence* o un caso de *comma splice*).

Lo correcto sería decir:

- Juan deberá comprar papas, carne, frutas y verduras. También deberá preguntar el precio de las zapatillas que tanto le gustan. ("gustan" porque "zapatillas" es plural.)

Después de "también", podría colocarse una coma (opcional).

- Juan deberá comprar papas, carne, frutas y verduras. También, deberá preguntar el precio de las zapatillas que tanto le gustan.

Podría usarse coma antes de "también" en este caso:

- Juan deberá comprar papas, carne, frutas y verduras, también.